# Reduce income tax payable in Canada for an individual taxpayer

Tags: income-tax, canada, tax-deduction, rrsp, canada-revenue-agency

For the 2023 tax year, in Canada, how can I reduce my personal taxable income/taxes payable on my T1 tax return? I know I can use my RRSP and a spousal RRSP as a deduction against taxable income up to Feb 29, 2024. Are there any other deductions/expenses I can make in 2024 that can be applied against my 2023 tax year?